# Can I Display Microphone status in top bar?

Tags: gnome, sound, 19.10, microphone

I like to use the global system shortcut for muting/unmuting my microphone during video calls. This has the great benefit of being available independent of video conferencing software.

However, sometimes it is hard to remember if the microphone is currently muted. I would like to see an icon that shows me the microphone status at all times. Ideally in the top bar next to the speaker icon.

I installed the [Sound Input & Output Device Chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/) gnome extension. It's a nice extension but only shows the microphone volume after a click on the speaker icon.

Is there any extension that solves my problem? Or another way to display microphone status *at all times*?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: My bad, I am actually using 19.10. The solution will be the same for all post-Unity versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After thinking I have to write my own Gnome extension for this, I tried all the existing ones again.

Turns out, [Nothing to say](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1113/nothing-to-say/) does almost exactly what I want.
It has some documentation on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/wbolster/nothing-to-say).

I was not able to find out how to use its push-to-talk feature that is described on the GitHub page, but I don't care about this anyway. Per default, push-to-talk does not seem to be active.

On my system, the extension's icon in the top bar becomes active whenever an application uses the microphone. If I then use the system-wide shortcut to mute the microphone, the extension icon changes and shows that the microphone is muted. This is perfect for me.

Comment: Regarding push-to-talk: It seems to use the same shortcut (windows+\ by default) as toggling, it works when you keep the key combo pressed rather than doing a quick press.

Comment: In my case, I always have the mic enabled, since I disable mic by hardware; HyperX wireless headset has a big button to disable mic input.

I need an extension that always shows mic levels on screen :(